# Displaying Google Calendar Data in an Android App

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, gdata

I'm trying to display google calendar events in my android app but nothing seems to work.  The calendar is one owned by a client and thus we cannot make their authentication credentials public.  I've tried using GData and OAuth but none seem to let us pull any events.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Up until very very recently there has been no official API for accessing google calendars in a purely android way. In short, you can't do this unless you're building for Ice Cream Sandwich. If your cool with only being able to target Ice Cream Sandwich and above, you can use the [CalendarContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html) API.

If you're dead set on interacting with google calendars and supporting more than just Ice Cream Sandwich, you could interface directly with the [google calendars api](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide.html). This will probably be pretty complicated though.